# How can I display multiple images from one folder in GUI written in Python?

Tags: python-3.7

I'm trying to display images of trash from a folder onto a page of my GUI and add labels underneath. I keep getting the "No such file or directory" error even though I thought i put the address of my folder named "Trash"

I've attached my code below:

```
    mypath='home/xinyi/Documents/Python/Trash'
    onlyfiles = [ f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath,f)) ]
    images = numpy.empty(len(onlyfiles), dtype=object)
    for n in range(0, len(onlyfiles)):
        images[n] = cv2.imread( join(mypath,onlyfiles[n]) )
```